# want to delete the related records only

Tags: sql

I have this trigger when I delete a record from the parent table Delete all records of the Jr. table but I want to delete the related records only What is the proposed amendment

```
CREATE TRIGGER ProductDeleted ON Product 
for DELETE AS 
BEGIN 

 DELETE FROM OrderItem WHERE ProductID = (SELECT ProductID FROM DELETED)
END
```

Comment: Tip: `IN` instead of `=`...

Comment: Why a trigger instead of an on delete cascade fk?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using?